# How can I store a calendar data in database

Tags: android, database, calendar

I want to store in my Android database a calendar entry.
It is no problem to store simple types like int and String in the database. But I cannot figure out how to store calendar type.

My table looks as follows:
reate table wishes(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "name text not null, "
            + "date text, picurl text, .....)

Everything is declared as "text".

In my activity I have this code:
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal should be stored in my table. Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the milliseconds from epoch representation of the calendar:

```
long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then store this long in the db. You can recover the calendar by reading the long value from the db and using `setTimeInMillis(long millis)` in the calendar.

Comment: How do I store the long value in my DB? Should I convert it to String?

Comment: SQLite supports long values as the "integer" data type, use that. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: You MIGHT in addition want to store it as a string, this allows you to read it if you are browsing your DB with a database browser that doesn't understand millis directly--but always use millis from code.

Answer (score 3):

To have a stable and localisation independend solution, I would suggest to change the database table to store the date as long. You can get the calendar date as long with `dateCalendar.getTimeInMillis()` and when you read it you add a line like

```
long dateAsMillis;
dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dateCalendar.setDate(dateAsMillis);
```

But if you really need/want to work with strings, have a look at [DateFormat.parse(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) - you can define the format your dates should have and therefore create a Date object from a String.

Comment: this is a very good idea. But how do I store the "long" in my database? At the moment every entry is "text"

Comment: Change your create statement of the database to: (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "name text not null, " + "date long, picurl text, .....)

Answer (score -2):

I would convert your Date into a String and store that string into the database.
Then when you read the String out from the database just parse it back into a Date.

Comment: This I already tried out. How do I parse the String to date back?

Comment: I would go with the long representation that the other guys are recommending. Its defiantly a way easier way to do it.

Comment: You are right. But how do I store the long value in my database?

Comment: You've never dealt with time zones, I'm guessing.  Even if you don't THINK you'll deal with time zones, always use millis, never rely on strings!